# Unlink and link product to category

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, category-products, category-tree

Need a script where current existing products needs to unlink and link to other categories.
let me know the process also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the code you will use in order to assign and unassign categories from product

```
 //Object Manager instance
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Product repository interface
 $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

//Load Product - assuming we have product id only
 $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load( $product_id );

$category_id = '34'; //Replace category id here

$product->setCategoryIds( array($category_id) ); //It accepts array so we can add multiple category ids.

try {
 $productRepository->save($product);
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
 // Handle error
 }
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: this one worked , thanks

Comment: hi @Hasham, can you look into this please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273968/how-tax-calculation-applied-for-two-different-product-with-different-tax-class-i

Answer (score 3):

Use below code to assign:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');

$category_ids = array('101','102');
$sku = '24-MB01';

$CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $category_ids);
```

And below to remove:

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

  $CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager- >get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository');

  $categoryId = 101;
  $sku = '24-MB01';

  $CategoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryId,$sku);
```